# sql query syntax case, join and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables:

```
mysql> desc macToNames;
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| mac   | varchar(17)   | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| Name  | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Seen  | decimal(10,0) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and

```
mysql> desc stats;
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| mac    | varchar(17)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ipAddr | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| epoch  | decimal(10,0) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| sent   | decimal(10,0) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| recv   | decimal(10,0) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have a query as below, with my limited `join` skills:

```
select case when macToNames.Name is null then stats.mac else macToNames.Name end as 'Hostname'
     ,stats.mac as 'mac',stats.ipAddr as 'ipAddr'
     ,stats.epoch as 'epoch'
     ,stats.sent as 'sent'
     ,stats.recv as 'recv' 
  from stats 
  left
  join macToNames 
    on macToNames.mac = stats.mac
  limit 5;
+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| Hostname          | mac               | ipAddr        | epoch      | sent     | recv      |
+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| x1                | 39-F2-BC-2F-4D-E9 | 192.168.1.232 | 1593836118 |   307197 |    623309 |
| someho-lxc        | 29-F2-BC-2F-4D-E9 | 192.168.1.52  | 1593836118 |  4273599 |   4207535 |
| 39-F2-BC-2F-4D-E9 | 39-F2-BC-2F-4D-E9 | 192.168.1.216 | 1593836118 |     4899 |      6503 |
| tinker            | 39-F2-AC-2F-4D-E9 | 192.168.1.166 | 1593836119 |    60312 |   8563601 |
| u1                | 3A-F2-BC-2F-4D-E9 | 192.168.1.172 | 1593836119 |      380 |       380 |
+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Here's where it gets difficult for me - I wish to run the above query as a sub-query

```
mysql> select Hostname,mac from (select case when macToNames.Name is null then stats.mac else macToNames.Name end as 'Hostname',stats.mac as 'mac',stats.ipAddr as 'ipAddr',stats.epoch as 'epoch',stats.sent as 'sent',stats.recv as 'recv' from stats left join macToNames on macToNames.mac=stats.mac);
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias
```

and, another:

```
mysql> select Hostname,mac,sum(stats.Sent)/(1000000000) as 'Sent',sum(stats.Recv)/1000000000 as 'Recv' group by mac from (select case when macToNames.Name is null then stats.mac else macToNames.Name end as 'Hostname',stats.mac as 'mac',stats.ipAddr as 'ipAddr',stats.epoch as 'epoch',stats.sent as 'sent',stats.recv as 'recv' from stats left join macToNames on macToNames.mac=stats.mac);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by mac from (select case when macToNames.Name is null then stats.mac else ' at line 1
```

I am trying to generate a report on total traffic by each mac, and also show the friendly name for that device. I am totally lost between the case and join - can you please point me the right direction?

Comment: You must give a name of the subquery when you use it in the FROM field. Just put "AS <name>" after the closing parenthesis ) of the sub-query. That was for the first query. As for the second one - GROUP BY must be after FROM and WHERE, not before them.

Comment: Side notes: T(1) he `CASE` expression can be replaced by `COALESCE(macToNames.Name, stats.mac)` which is the typical way to deal with such cases. (2) Pay attention to your quotes.  Use single quotes for string literals and double quotes for names. Hence: `as "epoch"`, not `as 'epoch'`. But why use name delimiters for such a simple name? You can just write `as epoch`, as there are no special characters or blanks in that name. And then, the name is already epoch, so why use an alias at all here?

Comment: Some more remarks: Why are mac and name nullable in macToNames? Shouldn't they be not nullable and even be the table's key? At least the table name suggests this. And are mac and ipAddr nullable in stats, because it suffices to have a value in either one column or the other? Or is this a mistake? At last, your sample data is confusing. There seems to be a row for mac = 39-F2-AC-2F-4D-E9 and name = 39-F2-AC-2F-4D-E9 (i.e. mac = name) in macToNames, which seems a bit weird.

Comment: Also note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As error indicates, you must provide an alias to derived tables or subqueries in `FROM` or `JOIN` clause. Additionally, for aggregate queries all `SELECT` columns must be present in `GROUP BY` (which follows `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses). Notice below all columns in top level is qualified by the alias `sub`. Also, your column aliases of `stats` fields are redundant since no expression is used and they repeat original column names. Finally, for many zeroes, use `E` for readability.

```
select sub.Hostname
       , sub.mac
       , sum(sub.Sent)/1E9 as 'Sent'
       , sum(sub.Recv)/1E9 as 'Recv' 
from 
  (select case 
              when macToNames.Name is null 
              then stats.mac 
              else macToNames.Name 
           end as 'Hostname'
           , stats.mac
           , stats.ipAddr
           , stats.epoch
           , stats.sent
           , stats.recv
    from stats 
    left join macToNames 
         on macToNames.mac=stats.mac
  ) as sub
group by sub.Hostname
       , sub.mac
```

In MySQL 8.0+, you can use [CTEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) in place of derived tables:

```
with sub AS (
   select case 
            when macToNames.Name is null 
            then stats.mac 
            else macToNames.Name 
          end as 'Hostname'
          , stats.mac
          , stats.ipAddr
          , stats.epoch
          , stats.sent
          , stats.recv
   from stats 
   left join macToNames 
         on macToNames.mac=stats.mac)

select sub.Hostname
       , sub.mac
       , sum(sub.Sent)/1E9 as 'Sent'
       , sum(sub.Recv)/1E9 as 'Recv' 
from sub
group by sub.Hostname
       , sub.mac
```